# Is Spring Security's BCrypt implementation vulnerable?

Tags: spring-security, bcrypt, jbcrypt

A security audit at our company found that the prefix of our bcrypt hashes are "$2a$". According to [1] and [2] this could indicate that an older, vulnerable bcrypt implementation is used.

So - here my questions:

1. Does Spring Security's bcrypt implementation contain the vulnerability?
2. Does Spring Security support the "$2x$" and "$2y$" prefixes?

References:
[1] http://blog.ircmaxell.com/2012/12/seven-ways-to-screw-up-bcrypt.html
[2] http://www.openwall.com/lists/oss-security/2011/06/21/16

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. The links you provide is about a vulnerability in the C implementation of BCrypt. The Spring Security implementation is a fork of [jBCrypt](https://code.google.com/p/jbcrypt/), which is a different implementation written in Java.
2. Looking at the [source code](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.springframework.security/spring-security-crypto/3.2.5.RELEASE/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCrypt.java), as of version 3.2.5, Spring Security doesn't support "$2x$" and "$2y$" prefixes. The implementation does not contain the C vulnerability but  it is not inter-operable with current C based implementation (like PHP).

Comment: There's a bug filed for jBCrypt to support the other hash prefixes: https://code.google.com/p/jbcrypt/issues/detail?id=9

Comment: @koe I don't think there is any development on Google Code site, last commit 2010 from what I can see.

Comment: That's right - there's no current SCM in place. I guess that's why Spring has forked/copied it and put the code on GitHub.