# Is there a way to check PHP-created bcrypt hashes with Spring Security?

Tags: java, php, spring, spring-security, bcrypt

#### Context

I am dealing with a PHP system using updated bcrypt algorithm (as there's been a known vulnerability in the underlying algorithm).

So PHP's [password_hash](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php) function now generates hashes prefixed with `$2y$`, as the old ones (prefixed with `$2a`) were vulnerable.

Spring Security's [BCrypt](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/4.2.5.RELEASE/apidocs/org/springframework/security/crypto/bcrypt/BCrypt.html) that I use in another Java system generates the original `$2a$` format hashes, as its underlying implementation (jBCrypt instead of C BCrypt as [mentioned in this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29740597/is-spring-securitys-bcrypt-implementation-vulnerable)) wasn't vulnerable to the same attack.

#### Problem

Checking PHP-generates hashes in Spring Security doesn't work. Is there a way to check PHP-generated hashes using Spring Security?

#### Example

```
php > $pwd = password_hash('foo', PASSWORD_BCRYPT, ['cost' => 12]);
php > echo $pwd;
$2y$12$TRc5ZjcmDJ8oFaoR1g7LD.RCxBTUZnGXB66EN9h9rKtNWg.hd7ExK
```

then using Java + Spring Security:

```
@Test
public void decryptsPhpHash() {
    boolean result = BCrypt.checkpw("foo", "$2y$12$TRc5ZjcmDJ8oFaoR1g7LD.RCxBTUZnGXB66EN9h9rKtNWg.hd7ExK");
    assertThat(result).isTrue();
}
```

throws the following error:

`java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid salt revision`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, PHP just changed the character a to y to distinguish it itself. Only PHP made this prefix change. So maybe just changing the y back to an a solves this issue.

> In June 2011, a bug was discovered in crypt_blowfish, a PHP implementation of BCrypt. It was mis-handling characters with the 8th bit set. They suggested that system administrators update their existing password database, replacing $2a$ with $2x$, to indicate that those hashes are bad (and need to use the old broken algorithm). They also suggested the idea of having crypt_blowfish emit $2y$ for hashes generated by the fixed algorithm.
>   Nobody else, including canonical OpenBSD, adopted the idea of 2x/2y. This version marker change was limited to crypt_blowfish. 
>   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bcrypt